# I'm having an issue with my code @ Python django blog Getting this error : AttributeError: module 'django.contrib.auth.admin' has no attribute 'site'

Tags: python, django

I'm having an issue with my code @ Python django  blog Getting this error : AttributeError: module 'django.contrib.auth.admin' has no attribute 'site'
Errror as below

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 848, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/martin/My-blog/mysite/urls.py", line 6, in <module>
    path(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
AttributeError: module 'django.contrib.auth.admin' has no attribute 'site'
```

My urls.py is as below

```
from django.urls import include, path
from django.contrib.auth import login
from django.contrib.auth import admin

urlpatterns =[
    path(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path(r'^accounts/login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'),
    path(r'^accounts/logout/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout', {'next_page': '/'}),
    path(r'', 'blog.urls'),
]
```

Comment: `from django.contrib.admin import site`

Comment: File "/home/martin/My-blog/mysite/urls.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.admin import site
ImportError: cannot import name 'site' from 'django.contrib.auth.admin' (/home/martin/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/admin.py)

Comment: thats the error i'm getting

Comment: you should remove the `.auth` part in your import...

Comment: Also for login?

Comment: For login its necessary though.

Comment: I did for admin

Answer (score 0):

`admin` is not a submodule of the `auth` module, it is a submodule of `django.contrib`. You thus import this with:

```
from django.urls import include, path
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView, LogoutView
from django.contrib.admin import site

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', site.urls),
    path('accounts/login/', LoginView.as_view()),
    path('accounts/logout/', LogoutView.as_view(next_page='/')),
    path('', include('blog.urls')),
]
```

Comment: path(r'^accounts/login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'),
  File "/home/martin/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 81, in _path
    raise TypeError('view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().')
TypeError: view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().

Comment: It brings me back to the include()

Comment: which i omitted due to  admin.site.urls.   django versions difference. They term include as an old model django 1. and ther like

Comment: @Martin: you should remove the strings, and replace it by the (class-based) views. The paths also do not work with regular expressions. Exactly where does this code sample originates from? Looks like it has some problems.

Comment: Initially it looked like this. Just went though debbuging one by one errors

Comment: @Martin: well `url` has been removed since Django-4.0, you can use `re_path` for regular expressions, but `path` works with a different syntax. Furthermore the `login` and `logout` have been removed since Django-3.2, these are now class-based views. Looks like you used a *very* old source that is deprecated.

Comment: Yes. Checkout original code urls.py below

Comment: thats 2016 code. I had a running blog.Just found out  alot changed sinse then